# How to hook in to bulk trash posts

Tags: bulk, trash

I am trying to hook into the trash post function in the bulk menu.

I've managed to hook into an item when I trash it by it self by using the `wp_trash_post` hook, but this does not work when doing it in bulk.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: This is because accepts only 1 parameter i.e the post id codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trash_post Can I know what exactly you are trying to do? Also provide some code.

Comment: Ok, what I am trying to do is delete an associated post (product post type) when my custom post type (video) is deleted and vice versa. This works when I delete a video post by itself but not when using the bulk delete. I have actually disabled the trash, so only deleting happens, but I asked this question with the wp_trash_post as it also will not work.

Comment: add_action('before_delete_post', 'delete_post_from_video');
function delete_post_from_video() {
 global $post; 
 global $wpdb; 
 if ($post->post_type == 'video') { 
  $check_attached_product = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'attached_product', true);   
  if ($check_attached_product != "") {
   delete_post_meta($post->ID, 'attached_product', $check_attached_product);
   wp_delete_post( $check_attached_product );  
  }   
 }