# How can i take all ids from untrash_post action?

Tags: posts, actions, id, trash

When the user chooses to restore **a** post ( *from "Trash" folder* ) with the following way, through the action [untrash_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/untrash_post), i get the **id** of the posts.

```
function my_untrash_post_type( $post_id )
{
    echo '<script> alert('.$post_id.'); </script>';
    wp_die('stop');
}

add_action('untrash_post' , 'my_untrash_post_type');
```

But if the user chooses more than one, posts to restore them, i cannot find the way in which will be able to get **all** the ids of the selected posts.
How could i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use transition_post_status:

```
add_action('transition_post_status', 'wpse_handle_untrash');
function wpse_handle_untrash($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
    // if the post was in the trash, but now is not
    if($old_status == 'trash') {
        // if you want, you can do something only for a certain post type
        if($post->post_type == 'my-desired-post-type') {
            // do something
            echo '<script>alert(' . $post->ID . ');</script>';
        }
    }
}
```

If you can explain what you'd like to do when a post is untrashed, that will be helpful in getting you a solution to accomplish it. Is a JS alert what you're ultimately hoping to achieve?

[This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125665/how-to-hook-in-to-bulk-trash-posts) may give you some ideas.

Comment: First of all you mean : `if($post->post_type == 'my-desired-post-type')` , right?

Thank you very much for your (quick) answer, but it didn't helped me in my problem. Because i want to know, **after** the action ( _"restore" - untrash_ ) be completed, **which posts have been restored**.
The code i have done so far and is not working is the [here](https://pastebin.com/7Ki2uspi).

Thanks you.

Comment: The code in this answer runs when a post status changes from being in the trash to not being in the trash. It contains the $post object so you can pull the ID from that post object. Since this code runs on any post status transition, the conditional for `$old_status == 'trash'` ensures it only runs when something is being moved out of the trash.

Comment: Yes, i agree with that.  Thanks you. But you've seen my code above ( in [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/7Ki2uspi) ) ?
What i really want is, if more than one post is selected, to be restored, after as soon as this happens, i display their ids. In my code, i use the `redirect_post_location` WordPress filter.

Comment: Any help about this problem?